# Show selected value when editing record

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

When editing a record, I want the dropdown to show the previously selected value.

Code is below:-

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit_model" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
           <h6 class="modal-title" >Model Title</h6>
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <form action="filename.php" method="post">
              <div class="form-group row">
                 <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                 <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" id="first_name" class="form-control rs_input" required >
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" id="last_name" class="form-control rs_input" required >
                 </div>
                 <select class="form-control" id="dropdown_id" name="dropdown_name">
                       <option >Select Value</option>

                       <?php
                          $dropdown = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM table") or die(mysqli_error($connect));
                          while ($fetch_data = mysqli_fetch_array($country)) {
                              ?>
                       <option value="<?php echo $fetch_data['id']; ?>"><?php echo $fetch_data['name']; ?></option>
                       <?php
                          } ?>
                    </select>
              </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:-

```
$('.class_name').on('dblclick',function(){
var value = $(this).attr("id");

$.ajax({
  url:"ajax/filename.php",
  method:"POST",
  data:{value:value},
  dataType:"json",
  success:function(data){

    $('#first_name').val(data.first_name);
    $('#last_name').val(data.last_name);
    $('#dropdown_id').val(data.dropdown_value);
)};
)};
```

To clarify, I want the previously selected value, that which is present in the record, to be selected in dropdown when a user edits the record. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `selected` tag, otherwise it will just populate the dropdown.

So, while looping the value, if you need to check which value has to be selected (if it is user specific).

```
if (some condition)
{
  <option selected="selected" ...
}
else
{
  <option ...
}
```

Comment: yeah....thanks for give me your time i understand but i don't know how i get data.dropdown value in my php code...???

Comment: @Luffy But, you just mentioned, *get all input filed value in my modal box*. That means, you have to check while looping.

Comment: yes you right but i don't know why but i can't get value in my php code.....i got firstname and lastname value through id in input filed

Comment: @Luffy did you get it, what I meant in my answer ?

Comment: yes i get what you meant of your answer but i confused in how i get previously record for dropdown selecetd value..

Comment: @Luffy, Ok, to select, previously selected value, you need to get the value first, which is selected and store it in some variable, then while populating drop down while using loop, add `if` condition (as I described in my answer). This way, if value matched, it will marked selected

Comment: yeah...thanks for help me now my issue is fix....and i really thank you for giving me your time..... @Ravi

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the previously selected value. Please see the code below:

```
<?php
$dropdown = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM table") or die(mysqli_error($connect));
while ($fetch_data = mysqli_fetch_array($country)) 
{
    if(*previously selected*)
    {
        echo '<option selected value="<?php echo $fetch_data['id']; ?>"><?php echo $fetch_data['name']; ?></option>'
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<option value="<?php echo $fetch_data['id']; ?>"><?php echo $fetch_data['name']; ?></option>'
    }   
}    
?>
```

Replace *previously selected* with the relevant check to see if the value was the previously selected value. If you require assistance with this, I will need to see the record side of things, if so, let me know.

Comment: can u please help me for understanding to how i get dropdown value from this line $('#dropdown_id').val(data.dropdown_value); in my php code ???